# CSS3 Animation on Button Click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a css3 animation to a button when it is clicked. (I want the button to zoom  in, spin and then zoom out so that it looks like it is flying off the screen.) I can get the animation to work if I make reference to the class that calls it in the markup. However, if I try to attach the css3 class using jquery the animation does not run. I have verified that the class is being attached via Firebug, but I still am not getting any animation. This is on a .NET .aspx page using a C# code behind. The CSS and markup are below:

```
 <%@ Page Title="About Us" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="MirandasWebsite.About" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<title>Contact Miranda</title>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#MainContent_imgbtnSendEmail").click(function() {  // this is your event
    $("#MainContent_imgbtnSendEmail").addClass("rotate");     // here your adding the new class
)}; 
)};
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEmail" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="ContactPage">
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlFacebook" runat="server" Visible="true">
                <div id="Facebook">
                    <div id="dFacebook" runat="server" class="zoom">
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hlFacebook" runat="server" Text="My Facebook">   </asp:HyperLink>
                    </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlPhone" runat="server">
                <br />
                <div id="lblPhone">
                <p>You may reach me at this number:</p>
                <span id="Phone" runat="server">
                </span>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSendEmail" runat="server" Visible="true">
                <br />
                <table id="ContactTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" runat="server" Text="Message Subject"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="tbwSubject" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSubject"
                                WatermarkText="Enter Message Subject Here">
                            </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqSubject" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSubject"
                                Text="**" ErrorMessage="A Message Subject is Required." Display="Static" CssClass="Validation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFrom" runat="server" Text="Your Email Address"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" Width="20%"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="tbwFrom" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFrom"
                                WatermarkText="Enter Your Email Address Here">
                            </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqFrom" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFrom"
                                Text="*" ErrorMessage="A Valid Email Address is Required." Display="Static" CssClass="Validation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexEmailAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtFrom"
                                ErrorMessage="A Valid Email Address is Required" ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
                                Display="Static" Text="*" CssClass="Validation"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBody" runat="server" Text="Message Body"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="25" Width="40%"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="tbwBody" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBody"
                                WatermarkText="Message Body Goes Here">
                            </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqBody" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBody"
                                ErrorMessage="A Message Body is Required." Display="Static" Text="**" CssClass="Validation"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%--<div id="SendEmail" runat="server" class="zoom"><asp:Button ID="btnSendEmail" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="btnSendEmail_Click" /></div>--%>
                            <div id="SendEmail" runat="server" class="zoom">
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnSendEmail" runat="server" OnClick="btnSendEmail_Click"
                                     ImageUrl="SiteImages/Mail-icon.png" /></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="validationSummary" ShowMessageBox="true"
                        ShowSummary="false" />
                </table>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlEmailSuccess" runat="server" Visible="false">
                <div id="MessageSuccess">
                    <h2>
                        The Email was Sent Successfully</h2>
                    <p>
                        Thank You for Your Interest</p>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="upprogRegister" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="blurred">
            <img src="SiteImages/ajax-loader.gif" id="blurredimage" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<asp:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender ID="aveProgressRegister" runat="server" TargetControlID="upprogRegister"
    HorizontalSide="Center" VerticalSide="Middle" UseAnimation="true">
</asp:AlwaysVisibleControlExtender>
</asp:Content>
```

CSS:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes rotater {
0% { transform:rotate(0) scale(1) }
10% { transform:rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) }
20% { transform:rotate(180deg) scale(2) }
30% { transform:rotate(270deg) scale(2.5) }
40% { transform:rotate(360deg) scale(3) }
50% { transform:rotate(450deg) scale(2.5) }
60% { transform:rotate(540deg) scale(2) }
70% { transform:rotate(630deg) scale(1.5) }
80% { transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1) }
90% { transform:rotate(810deg) scale(.5) }
100% { transform:rotate(900deg) scale(0) }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotater {
0% { transform:rotate(0) scale(1) }
10% { transform:rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) }
20% { transform:rotate(180deg) scale(2) }
30% { transform:rotate(270deg) scale(2.5) }
40% { transform:rotate(360deg) scale(3) }
50% { transform:rotate(450deg) scale(2.5) }
60% { transform:rotate(540deg) scale(2) }
70% { transform:rotate(630deg) scale(1.5) }
80% { transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1) }
90% { transform:rotate(810deg) scale(.5) }
100% { transform:rotate(900deg) scale(0) }
}

@-o-keyframes rotater {
0% { transform:rotate(0) scale(1) }
10% { transform:rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) }
20% { transform:rotate(180deg) scale(2) }
30% { transform:rotate(270deg) scale(2.5) }
40% { transform:rotate(360deg) scale(3) }
50% { transform:rotate(450deg) scale(2.5) }
60% { transform:rotate(540deg) scale(2) }
70% { transform:rotate(630deg) scale(1.5) }
80% { transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1) }
90% { transform:rotate(810deg) scale(.5) }
100% { transform:rotate(900deg) scale(0) }
}

@-ms-keyframes rotater {
0% { transform:rotate(0) scale(1) }
10% { transform:rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) }
20% { transform:rotate(180deg) scale(2) }
30% { transform:rotate(270deg) scale(2.5) }
40% { transform:rotate(360deg) scale(3) }
50% { transform:rotate(450deg) scale(2.5) }
60% { transform:rotate(540deg) scale(2) }
70% { transform:rotate(630deg) scale(1.5) }
80% { transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1) }
90% { transform:rotate(810deg) scale(.5) }
100% { transform:rotate(900deg) scale(0) }
}

@keyframes rotater {
0% { transform:rotate(0) scale(1) }
10% { transform:rotate(90deg) scale(1.5) }
20% { transform:rotate(180deg) scale(2) }
30% { transform:rotate(270deg) scale(2.5) }
40% { transform:rotate(360deg) scale(3) }
50% { transform:rotate(450deg) scale(2.5) }
60% { transform:rotate(540deg) scale(2) }
70% { transform:rotate(630deg) scale(1.5) }
80% { transform:rotate(720deg) scale(1) }
90% { transform:rotate(810deg) scale(.5) }
100% { transform:rotate(900deg) scale(0) }
}

.rotate 
{ 
   -webkit-animation-name: rotater;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

  -moz-animation-name: rotater;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-duration: 1s;

  -o-animation-name: rotater;
  -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -o-animation-duration: 1s;

  animation-name: rotater;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
   }
```

Comment: you probably get redirected if it's submitting a form...before the animation can even happen. Also, please just show *rendered* code. There's no point in asking a front-end question, and showing back-end code. *and* as one last point, you don't need to include all the vendor prefixes in your question

Comment: It's not redirecting, I have not added the redirect logic to the button click yet. I am waiting until the animation is executing in a manner that I like then I will create a timer function to allow the animation to play then submit the form. Also, what do you mean by rendered code vs back-end code?

Comment: because this question is not related to asp.net templating whatsoever. if you want people to answer dont give them something not related to the question. the asp code doesnt make sense in a html/js context.

Comment: here is a jsFiddle so we can talk about this more specifically. http://jsfiddle.net/Q3rZ4/

Comment: @ArashMilani Thank you for setting that jsFiddle up! I played around with it a little bit and found that it worked in FF but not Chrome, I was missing some vendor tags, but when I put the code exactly as it appeared in the jsFiddle back into my project I am still getting no changes from the Css class.

Comment: is this part of your code working? `$("#MainContent_imgbtnSendEmail").addClass("rotate");` is there such element in the web page?

Comment: @ArashMilani Yes, that is what the asp:ImgButton ID="imgbtnSendEmail" is rendered as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was not exactly how I wanted to handle it, but I got it working. I added an OnClientClick event to the image button, like so:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnSendEmail" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:addSendAnimation()"  OnClick="btnSendEmail_Click"
                                     ImageUrl="SiteImages/Mail-icon.png" /></div>
```

and then create two JS functions like this:

```
function addClassName(inElement, inClassName) {
if (!hasClassName(inElement, inClassName))
    inElement.className = [inElement.className, inClassName].join(' ');
}

function addSendAnimation() {
var button = document.getElementById('MainContent_imgbtnSendEmail');
addClassName(button, 'rotate');
alert(button + " was clicked"); //This is used for debugging and should be removed before the site goes live
}
```